# Is there a way I can find wordpress posts that don't contain a word?

Tags: plugins, functions, search, phpmyadmin

Am trying to unpublish wordpress posts that don't contain a word., Its like the inverse of search, Search is finding a string in wordpress posts, I need to find wordpress posts,. I think this will be useful to many, since We can have a magic word that tells us if a plugin is working correctly or not in a post., and there by find all posts that can be saved as drafts and worked upon individually.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simple query and loop with [wp_update_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) function to update the post providing ID, post type by checking the words with [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

The following example shows a simple update to the post status for all posts in a loop for which post title does not contain `Hello` or content does not contain `Hello`.

The following code is proved to work by just putting in theme functions.php .

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // any post type
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'private', 'draft' ), // any types
);

$query_post = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query_post->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $query_post->have_posts() ) {
        $query_post->the_post();

        $postarr = array(
            'ID' => get_the_ID(),
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish', // change to other type needed such as draft
        );

        // eg. if not contain specific words in title or content
        if( ! preg_match( "/Hello/", get_the_title() ) || ! preg_match( "/Hello/", get_the_content() ) ) {
            $result = wp_update_post( $postarr );

            // for debug
            var_dump($result); // (int|WP_Error) The post ID on success. The value 0 or WP_Error on failure.
        }

    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

For some cases, depends on the loading of plugin and theme settings, putting inside a hook such as `init hook` will ensure it run with all necessary components is loaded

```
// in functions.php

add_action( 'init', 'ws365194_my_test' );
function ws365194_my_test() {

   // paste above code here and run

}
```

Comment: I can just copy this code into functions.php. is that all?. or do I have to create a function, and call it through add_filter?

Comment: If for ***a test run***, put in theme's function.php, ***the best inside the filter function add_action( 'init', 'my_function');*** since I am not sure which page are you going to test. If for advanced use such as putting inside a plugins, that's another story, you may put anywhere in the plugins as you like as long as you could call it. Remember to change the post status in the example. From 'public' to 'draft' if you want to reset to draft.